# how to retrieve yesteraday inserted records in a table?

Tags: mysql

how to retrieve yesteraday inserted records in a table?Note there is no timestamp column in a table

Comment: Do you have the facility to add a timestamp column?

Comment: if i add timestamp what would be the query Delan?

Answer (score 3):

If you have no timestamp column or other source of relative information stored, then the only possible way is to restore yesterday's backup and compare the two databases / tables.

**Edit** (example provided)

```
SELECT * FROM today.table t1 LEFT JOIN yesterday.table t2
    on t1.id = t2.id WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

This will work provided each day's backup is created before the start of the day.

Answer (score 1):

if u do only insert queries to this table , its **Enough** to store only the **max id** of the table (last id) per day,(if you have auto increment primary key) 
you can store the max id from yesterday and

```
select from table where id > last_max_id
```